# How to add CFLAGS in makefile.am

Tags: c, linux, makefile, yocto

I m using `Makefile.am` in `yocto` source.

My code is working with normal `Makefile`.

But, while integrating with the `Makefile.am` in `yocto`, It's getting segmentation faults.

I m using -`lpthread` while compilation. I want to know how to use
   `cflags` in `Makefile.am`. Can anyone tell me if my `Makefile.am` is correct? Because I'm doubting about my compilation.

Below is my `Makefile.am`

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -static -lpthread -lrt
#include_HEADERS = .Iinclude/*
nobase_include_HEADERS = include/fmsHeader.h include/c_typedef.h include/console_comm.h

bin_PROGRAMS = bbmain
bbexample_SOURCES = bbmain.c
```

Answer (score 2):

I re-modified the contents into below format. **It works**

Hope it may helpful for someone.

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

CFLAGS +=-Wall -Wextra
LDFLAGS=-lpthread -lrt

nobase_include_HEADERS = Headers/console_comm.h Headers/c_typedef.h Headers/fmsHeader.h

bin_PROGRAMS=fmsTestApp
test_SOURCES=fmsTestApp.c

bin_PROGRAMS: 
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ ${test_SOURCES}
```

Comment: This is not good, you will overwrite user-provided `CFLAGS`. It should be `CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra $(CFLAGS)`, the difference is that `CFLAGS` is explicitly appended. So for example, you may set `-Og`, but user don't want optimization and passes `CFLAGS=-O0` on command line. By using `CFLAGS += -Og` your `-Og` will take over the user provided value. But by appending CFLAGS on top of yours you make sure the user provided `-O0` takes the priority.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems with your suggested makefile (in the question):

1. Don't use `=` in Makefile.am, as that makes it more difficult to control the base flags from outside. Use `+=` instead.
2. As you've correctly noticed, `CFLAGS` is for *compilation* flags. Unfortunately, `LDFLAGS` is also wrong, as that's used for linker *flags*. You should add the flags to `LIBS`.
3. Don't use `-lpthread`, ever. Use `-pthread` instead. Also, note that `-pthread` is a compilation flag, as well as a link time flag.
4. Personally, I like to add flags such as `-Wall` and `-Wextra` through the configure script, and not as part of the makefile itself. It makes it easier to control its use.

End result should look something like this:

```
CFLAGS += -pthread
LIBS += -lrt
```

Comment: `-pthread` is a linkage option. Consult the manual [3.14 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

Comment: Did you read the link you provided? Particularly the part that says:  "On some targets this option also sets flags for the preprocessor, so it should be used consistently for both compilation and linking."?

Comment: Yes I know the link well. It is categorically false that `-pthread`
"is not a link time flag", as you stated, and for those recondite
targets where it is also significant to the preprocessor, for dependeable
effect it needs to appear in the C preprocessor flags (`CPPFLAGS`) as well as the
linker flags, rather than the C compiler flags (`CFLAGS`), as you also stated.

Comment: `-pthread` is a flag that affects both compilation and linking. As such, it is not a link time flag. `CPPFLAGS` are flags directed at the preprocessor. `-pthread` is not such a flag (check the flags that `cpp` accept). It is a flag for the *compiler* that affects preprocessor definitions and linker options (`ld` also doesn't know it). `CFLAGS` is the right place to put it. It is also the only place to put it so that it is passed both at compile time and at link time.

Comment: With that said, I did edit the answer to say "as well as" instead of "not a".

Comment: "As such, it is not a link time flag". You mean it is not *only* a link time flag, which I know.
I also know `-pthread` is not an option of `cpp`, just as it not an option of `ld`.
It is a *preprocessing option of GCC* and (separately) a *linkage option of GCC*. See
the manual [3.12 Options Controlling the Preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)
again.

Comment: See [the effect of `-pthread` on preprocessing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70a77b408314e610),
and the [effect of its absence on preprocessing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d87e0346f7a246fa).
See the [effect of its presence in preprocessing and absence for linkage](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8d44cc4f5826145)

Comment: And the correct place to pass gcc flags is in `CFLAGS`. I fail to see what it is about my answer you do not like.